# Encontrar perguntas/respostas vinculadas as minhas

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso

Existe alguma forma mais simples de saber que alguma pergunta ou resposta referenciou/vinculou uma minha?

Se eu entrar pergunta por pergunta que eu fiz, eu consigo visualizar se ela foi vinculada a outro conteúdo, mas existe outra maneira?

Outro ponto que gostaria de levantar, se seria viável receber uma notificação quando seu conteúdo for vinculado ou adicionar uma nova aba na minha página para exibir os vínculos.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que de forma completa só usando o [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Acho pouco provável que vão colocar o recurso pedido, mas não deixa de ser uma boa.

Answer (score 12):

A url é esta:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/<ID da sua pergunta>?lq=1
```

Por exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/43193?lq=1

> **Nota:** A unica coisa que de fato falta para esta página é um feed (rss/atom), assim como a maioria das páginas do de perguntas e tags tem.

### Extra

Note que a Stack Overflow oferece uma [API](https://api.stackexchange.com) para usar nos sites da rede, (semelhante a API de serviços como Facebook), o qual lhe permite criar suas próprias aplicações, no caso com ela você pode acessar os caminhos:

- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions (busca perguntas linkadas), exemplo de uso:

  ```
  https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/43193/linked?page=1&pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=activity&site=pt.stackoverflow
  ```
- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions (busca postagens relacionadas, provavelmente identificada pelo próprio sistema), exemplo de uso:

  ```
  https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/43193/linked?page=1&pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=activity&site=pt.stackoverflow
  ```

Comment: Boa, não sabia disso. Acho que não tem uma mais geral com tudo o que foi *linkado* pra coisas suas, né? Acho que só funciona pra pergunta, né?

Comment: @bigown respostas não tem vinculo, mesmo que você link uma resposta ainda sim o vinculo será a postagem principal, que no caso é a pergunta, pois os links das respostas são atalhos para os links das perguntas com hash (fragmento: `#`)

Comment: Pra mim ñ importa muito porque eu "sempre" *linko* a pergunta, mas tem gente que vai na resposta. O que eu queria é um lugar que mostrasse tudo o que tem *link* pra perguntas onde tenham resposta minhas. Aí só SEDE.

Comment: @bigown posso estar falando besteira, mas se usar `/answers/{ids}/questions` pegar todos IDs das questões retornado e depois usar `/questions/{ids}/linked`, terá o resultado desejado (note que todos com `/answers` requerem autenticação). Só não irei adicionar a resposta porque não testei ainda.